# Sharepoint: SPweb.Groups.GetByName(groupName) throwing exception

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to create a new SharePoint group programmatically (using .Net), for this I am using the following C# code

```
                //greate group with no users:

                web.SiteGroups.Add(groupName, groupOwner, null, description);
                //Parameters are defined earlier in the code such as:
                //   string groupName
                //   SPUser groupOwner
                //   string description

                web.Update();
                SPGroup newGroup = web.Groups.GetByName(groupName);
```

The creation works well but when I try to access the group an exception is thrown saying "Group cannot be found."
What is the reason that the group can not be found and how can I fix this (I need to access the group for my further code)? If I check on the SharePoint  under People and Groups the group is there.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You should try on [SharePoint dedicated StackExchange Site](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : SPGroup oGroup = web.SiteGroups[groupName];

Answer (score 2):

I think, Aanchal's code will throw an exception, if the group is not existing.

Please check this code snippet. It worked fine for me to check if a group exists:

```
string nameOfGroupToCheck = "Test Group";
if (spWeb.Groups.OfType<SPGroup>().Where(g => g.Name == nameOfGroupToCheck).Count() > 0)
{
...
}
```

To get this code work correctly, you need to add the `System.Linq` namespace to your code:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the reason that the group can not be found

That occurs because `Groups` property contains only groups that you granted any kind of permissions in the `web` scope.

> how can I fix this

You should use `SiteGroups` instead. This property contains all groups added to the sitecollection your `web` is under. Also, your newly created group.

Your code should be ok with `GetByName`, but be warned that if you use it somewhere else you're not sure the group exists, it can throw an exception if the group does not exist.

If you need this and don't want to add a try/catch clause neither use `System.Linq`, you could do something like:

```
SPGroupCollection groups = web.SiteGroups.GetCollection(new string[] { groupName });                    
SPGroup myGroup = groups.Count == 0 ? null : groups[0];

if (myGroup != null)
{
    // ...
}
```